# change value of a variable with ng-change function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an item in an object `c.data.requiredAttachmentUploaded = false` I need to make it "true" when a file is selected in `<input type="file" >`

So I am trying to do it with ng-change but it's not working, even console.log is not working.
Is ng-change is appropriate for this task ?

APP.JS

```
app.controller('taskSummaryAndAction', [ 
  function() {

    c = this; //declare c internally 
    c.data = {}; //setup our data object (To be used in later steps)

    c.data.requiredAttachmentUploaded = false;

    c.attachmentChange = function() {  
      console.log('Hello');
      c.data.requiredAttachmentUploaded = true;
    }; 

  }
]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="taskSummaryAndAction as c">

    Input File here :

    <input type="file" ng-change="attachmentChange()"
           ng-model="c.data.requiredAttachmentUploaded">

</div>
```

I can easily do this with jQuery but I need to do this with AngularJS.
I m not even getting an error in Console.

Comment: [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) says: "*Note: Not every feature offered is available for all input types. Specifically, data binding and event handling via ng-model is unsupported for input[file].*"

Comment: ng-change="c.attachmentChange()"

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, I learnt that usage of ng-change is different for `<input type="file" >`
So I made some change in my controller and my HTML.

JS:

```
app.controller('taskSummaryAndAction', [ '$scope',
  function($scope) {
    c = this; //declare c internally 
    c.data = {}; //setup our data object (To be used in later steps)
    c.data.requiredAttachmentUploaded = false;

    $scope.attachmentChange = function() {  

      c.data.requiredAttachmentUploaded = true;
      console.log(c.data.requiredAttachmentUploaded);
    }; 

  }
]);
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().attachmentChange()" ng-model="file">
```

Comment: You should not use `angular.element(this).scope()`

Comment: @BillP Yes you are right. I'm stuck again, I didn't realize, I am using `onchange` . I needed to use `ng-change` .